# How to count words in a Greek text

Tags: string-manipulation

I want to perform a simple analysis of some Greek text: collect the different words used and count their frequency. It seems that some of the built-in commands do not work well with Greek letters. For instance, with

```
words = StringCases["α β1 rpr other", WordCharacter ..]
```

the output is

```
{"1", "rpr", "other"}
```

How do I get *Mathematica* to recognize other kinds of words?

Comment: FWIW, you might consider something like `StringCases["α β1 rpr0 other", RegularExpression["(\\w|[\[CapitalAlpha]-ω])+"]]`. A bit cumbersome, but there ya go... with the caveat that this can't handle characters with *tonos*; you'll have to modify the regex as needed.

Comment: It'd good to be aware of this: http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2009/Jul/msg00398.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have partial success in splitting Greek text:

```
greek = ExampleData[{"Text", "HomerOdysseyGreek"}]
Style[StringTake[greek, 100], FontFamily -> "Times"]
Style[StringSplit[StringTake[greek, 100], " "], FontFamily -> "Times"]
```

[image: greek]

Comment: `StringSplit` is essentially all I need, and it works great. It correctly identifies words in the Greek.

Answer (score 7):

I'd say this is either a programming or a documentation bug.

The documentation for `WordCharacter` says:

> WordCharacter matches any character for which either LetterQ or DigitQ yields True. »

Well, `WordCharacter` clearly doesn't consider alpha a letter:

```
StringMatchQ["α", WordCharacter]
```

> False

but `LetterQ` does:

```
LetterQ["α"]
```

> True

A workaround:

```
theGreeks=Alternatives@@Select[CharacterRange["\[CapitalAlpha]", "\[Omega]"], LetterQ];

StringCases["α β1 rpr other", (WordCharacter | theGreeks) ..]
```

> {"α", "β1", "rpr", "other"}

You may want to enlarge the set of characters included in "theGreeks". Now only, the basic Greek characters are in there.

Comment: FWIW, both `StringMatchQ["α", RegularExpression["[[:word:]]"]]` and `StringMatchQ["α", RegularExpression["\\w"]]` also return `False`.